# Rails 3.1 - How do you include external javascript libraries in vendor/assets/javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

In mulitple views I am including an external javascript library with this HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js">
</script>
```

In reading through the Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline documentation and discussions I get the impression that `vendor/assets/javascripts` is a place were that file should be referenced.  I'm guessing that I could download a copy of the file (`jstree.js`) and place it in that directory. However I'd like to have it loaded off the project site instead of making a local copy of it.

What do I put in vendor/assets/javascripts to pull a copy of jstree.js off the remote server?  Do I create a .js file with some sort of remote load code?  There seems to be all sorts of approaches and/or confusion on how to best do this ( see the long list of answers to this question:  [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) .)

Is there a "Rails Standard" convention/library/process for doing this?  I'm a javascript neophyte, so please be explicit, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there's no way you can put a "reference" to a remote file in the assets folder. You either download a copy and put into assets, or reference remote file with `<script>` tag.

Having a copy is not a bad idea, really. At least, you know that it works and the file hasn't changed (unless you changed it yourself). When you load a remote file, all sorts of surprises can happen :)

Comment: Thanks.  Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious and you confirmed that.  Don't quite agree having a local copy is a good idea (except in production.)  Libraries have learned to have "stable" versions that are never changed, so I'm not too concerned about that.  If Rails supported a "reference" system (something like a Gemfile) I could more easily maintain my various JS libraries in dev/test/production.  I would not have to manually download/organize files and could avoid the sprockets confusion. Would be super easy to dev/test against a new version of the remote library.

Comment: I'm not sure it is always a good practice to store all of your JS files locally. Using third party services, like social buttons, it can be a lot of heart ache to debug if they change the service.

Comment: +1 on a Gemfile for remotely stored JS files. @Don Could even include remotely downloading them per deploy, but locally serving them via sprockets.